# in javascript for loop is executing before the get method executes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following example variable `e` contains all the selected clients from a select box, I am iterating them one by one in a `for` loop and passing them via jQuery's get method to take values according to client but the `for` loop is executing before get method ends and due to that it changes the value of val (which is next value). How to resolve this problem ?

```
var e = document.getElementById("client");
for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length; i++) {
    if (e.options[i].selected) {
        var val = e.options[i].value;
        alert(val); // here it is coming normally

        $('#fund').append('<option value=' + select.options.length + '>---' + val + '----</option>');   
        $.get("listFundsForClient", { client: val }, function(data) {
            alert("2nd:" + val);// here it is taking next value due to for loop iteration
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: because the `$.get()` is an asynchronous method

Comment: [AJAX 25:17](http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/1klgf6/ajax_2517/)

Comment: Use `(function(val) {})(val)` trick

Comment: @Marc Because ham and hamsters are the same thing too.

Comment: as Arun said get() is asynchronous, maybe you can find useful a callback function. see here: [http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the call using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to  do it synchronously, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  async: false,
  data: myData,
  success: function(data) {
    //stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

it is because here `val` is a closure variable, it can be re-written as

```
$('#client option:selected').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), val =$this.val();
    alert(val); // here it is coming normally

    $('#fund').append('<option value='+select.options.length+'>---'+val+'----</option>');   
    $.get("listFundsForClient", {client: val}, function(data) {
        alert("2nd:"+val);// here it is taking next value due to for loop iteration
    });
})
```

Comment: can you please explain me what you have done or just provide me some link to refer.

Comment: read about variable scope and closures https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: @adityasingh also I've used jQuery selectors to fetch the selected options instead of pure javascript because it is less code

Comment: i meant this is giving the same problem which i had mentioned in question.